# Custom Function for obtaining URL directory

Tags: regex, r, strsplit

Looks quite easy,

Consider the following URLs,

```
[1] "scripts.iucr.org/cgi-bin/paper?S1600536812045886"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
[2] "cpa-seoadvisors.com/cvv/auth/auth/view/pdf/index.html/"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
[3] "www.scirp.org/journal/PaperDownload.aspx?DOI=10.4236/csta.2012.13014"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[4] "www.google.com.cy/search?q=DNS+traffic&es_..."                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
[5] "seesaa.net/pede/lobortis/ligula/sit/amet.png?semper=vitae&est=..."
```

I want to get the part between the first `'/'` and the one that separates the token with the `?`. 
I wrote the following function

```
get_directory <- function(x){
  dir <- sapply(strsplit(x, '/'), function(i)sum(grepl('\\?', i)))
  ifelse(dir > 0, sapply(strsplit(x, '/'), function(i) paste(i[-c(1, length(i))], collapse = '/')), 0)
}
```

But it fails at [3] and [4] URL.

Expected output should be

```
"cgi-bin"
"0"
"journal"
"0"
"pede/lobortis/liguls/sit"
```

**DATA**

```
dput(df)
structure(list(V1 = c("scripts.iucr.org/cgi-bin/paper?S1600536812045886", 
"cpa-seoadvisors.com/cvv/auth/auth/view/pdf/index.html/", "www.scirp.org/journal/PaperDownload.aspx?DOI=10.4236/csta.2012.13014", 
"www.google.com.cy/search?q=DNS+traffic&es_...", "seesaa.net/pede/lobortis/ligula/sit/amet.png?semper=vitae&est=..."
)), .Names = "V1", row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You return "0" in `ifelse` if `sum(grepl('\\?', i))` - null..( if there isn `t ? in string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `str_extract`.  Using the regex lookarounds, we match one or more characters (`.*`) that succeed a `/` followed by a `/` and one or more characters that are not `?` (`[^?]+`) followed by a `?`.

```
library(stringr)
res <- str_extract(df$V1, "(?<=\\/).*(?=\\/[^?]+[?])")
res[is.na(res)] <- 0
res
#[1] "cgi-bin"                  "0"                        "journal"                 
#[4] "0"                        "pede/lobortis/ligula/sit"
```